# Use Foreign Key on SQL View in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, sql-view

I'm relatively new to Entity Framework.

I created a database with two tables: `Accounts` and `Assignments`.

`Accounts` has an `AccountId` primary key which is used as a foreign key in the `Properties` table.  I really like that the Entity Framework automatically picks up the foreign key relationship and allows me to access rows in `Assignments` as a property of each row from `Accounts`.

I went ahead and created a new View object that returns all the columns from `Accounts` along with some other information.  However, when I get the data from the View in SQL using the Entity Framework, it is no longer automagically referencing the associated rows in the `Assignments` table.

How can I get the desired behavior using Views with Entity Framework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can work in EF, but the EF designer can't infer your FK out of the view, since the DB doesn't tell it where the FKs on view columns are (since they're naturally on the underlying tables, not the view itself).

You'll need to [manually edit your EDMX, either via the designer or in XML, to get these properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465855/entity-framework-add-navigation-property-manually).

Comment: It's been more than 4 years, is this answer still the only way? I could not spot an alternative automated solution when searching on the web.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to include the appropriate data in the view so I didn't need to use the FK.

For example, include the PK's for the Assignment table in the view by adding the appropriate SQL to the view.

That way I could join to the view in LINQ without needing to refer to a generated property in the EDMX.