# SQL View Script for Entity Framework related entities

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sql-view

I'm working on creating a SQL view and ultimately, I would like to add the view to my Entity Framework model. I understand that this can simply be done in Entity Framework but I am just experimenting with views and need to work on my SQL skills.

Let's imagine a scenario where I am pulling data from a table called Sates. State has a 0->n association to another table called City. City has a 0-n association to another table called Streets.

So my script would be something similar to:

```
SELECT st.Name, st.ID FROM Test.States s
LEFT OUTER JOIN Test.Cities c on c.StateID = s.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Test.Streets str on str.CityID = c.ID
```

What do I need to add to the View script to grab all the corresponding Cities and Streets in the hierarchy shown below? I basically want my View entity to have the Cities and Streets collections populated:

```
public partial class StateView
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
}

public partial class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Street> Streets { get; set; }
}
```

P.S. my goal here is to make one trip to the DB, Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could expand your view to simply include the additional fields in the results, then process the data in-code.

```
create view TestView
SELECT s.Name as sName, s.ID as sID, 
c.ID as cID, c.Name as cName, 
str.ID as strID, str.Name as strName  
FROM Test.States s
LEFT OUTER JOIN Test.Cities c on c.StateID = s.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Test.Streets str on str.CityID = c.ID
```

After added to an EF model, process as needed... e.g. for a simplified c# DataContext/LINQ setup:

```
YourDataContext dc = new YourDataContext();

//Single call to DB here
var newObj =
(from p in dc.TestView
group p by new { p.sID, p.sName } into g
select new StateView
{
    ID = g.sID,
    Name = g.sName,
    Cities = from pp in g.cID 
             group pp by new { pp.cID, pp.cName } into gg
             select new City
             {
                  ID = gg.cID
                  Name = gg.cName,
                  Streets = gg.Streets.ToList()

             }
}).toList();
```

**Note this code is untested, and may require tweaking.**

The idea is to include all of the data in your initial view, then process the view into your objects using grouping in LINQ. Without having a Street structure, I just toList()'ed it (would need to be modified for Street structure instead). The resulting object should be a List with all of the child properties set as well.

Comment: the ToList() on Streets would be an extra call to the DB for each city. This assumes eager loading where in some cases, you want lazy loading

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add manual associations through the edmx model.

Please refer to:
[Entity Framework - Add Navigation Property Manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465855/entity-framework-add-navigation-property-manually)
for additional info.