# Type-casting entity framework results in ItemDataBound

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

So I've trying to optimize performance of a page which generates the navigation menu for a website. Basically there is a table called T_product_cat which contains 4 fields I care about:

- product_cat_name (the product category name)
- product_cat_uid (the unique identifier of the row)
- product_cat_thumbnail_path (the image that represents the category)
- product_cat_parent_uid (the unique identifier of the product category
  that we sit underneath - since these "product folders" can nest)

I need to create a top navigation bar which has just the names of the top level product categories and then for the dropdown navigation I need to output the sub product categories along with their images and links etc. I've got a basic ASP:Repeater control with a nested ASP:Repeater to handle the sub-product categories

Basically though I want to start using EF to start querying for my data. Initially I did a query to just pull the top level items and then in the ItemDataBound event of the repeater, I'd access the data and query the database again for the sub categories. But this was hitting the database 8x (since I've got 7 top level categories). To speed things up I've been trying different iterations of an initial query. Here's my final one for reference:

```
Using db As New RmpEntities
    ' query all the items and then all their subitems at the same time so that we don't have to repeatedly hit the database
    Dim qry = (
        From
            productCat In db.T_product_cat
        Where
            productCat.company_uid = WmsSession.company_uid AndAlso
            productCat.enabled = 1 AndAlso
            productCat.product_cat_parent_uid = GUIDs.GlobalGuids.RootCategoryUid AndAlso
            productCat.product_cat_hide <> 1
        Order By
            productCat.product_cat_sequence
        Select
            categoryName = productCat.product_cat_name,
            categoryUid = productCat.product_cat_uid,
            imagePath = productCat.product_cat_thumbnail_path,
            subCategories = (
                From
                    productSubCat In db.T_product_cat
                Where
                    productSubCat.company_uid = WmsSession.company_uid AndAlso
                    productSubCat.enabled = 1 AndAlso
                    productSubCat.product_cat_parent_uid = productCat.product_cat_uid AndAlso
                    productSubCat.product_cat_hide <> 1
                Order By
                    productSubCat.product_cat_sequence
                Select
                    categoryName = productSubCat.product_cat_name,
                    categoryUid = productSubCat.product_cat_uid,
                    imagePath = productSubCat.product_cat_thumbnail_path
            )
    )
    rptMainNav.DataSource = qry.ToList()
    rptMainNav.DataBind()
End Using
```

When the repeater's ItemDataBound event fires I do have working code to pick apart the results and bind the data to the sub-repeater (this code works):

```
Protected Class CategoryInfo
    Public Property categoryName As String
    Public Property categoryUid As Guid
    Public Property imagePath As String
End Class

Private Sub rptMainNav_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptMainNav.ItemDataBound
    Dim rItem As RepeaterItem = e.Item
    Select Case rItem.ItemType
        Case ListItemType.Item, ListItemType.AlternatingItem
            Dim dataItem = rItem.DataItem
            Dim subRepeater As Repeater = rItem.FindControl("rptSubNav")
            Dim parentUid As Guid = dataItem.categoryUid
            Dim st = DateTime.Now
            Dim x As New List(Of CategoryInfo)
            For Each item In dataItem.subCategories
                x.Add(New CategoryInfo With {.categoryName = item.categoryName, .categoryUid = item.categoryUid, .imagePath = item.imagePath})
            Next
            subRepeater.DataSource = x
            dTime.Add(New MyTimes With {.g = parentUid, .ts = DateTime.Now - st})
            subRepeater.DataBind()
    End Select
End Sub
```

But how can I cast the Object type returned by accessing the repeater's DataItem to a more strongly-typed object so I can get intellisense?
Or is there some way I can give up on the worries about typing and just use the query results directly as a DataSource for the sub-repeater? That was my first goal but when I tried to take

```
dataItem.subCategories.ToList()
```

It failed with:

```
Public member 'ToList' on type 'CompensatingCollection(Of VB$AnonymousType_1(Of String,Guid,String))' not found.
```

When I tried to modify my CategoryInfo class to have another property to hold a list of CategoryInfo classes (subcategories) and have the main query return structured data (so I'd have a type to cast to in the ItemDataBound) things failed even worse. The original query's .ToList failed so I couldn't even do the initial bind.

What is the correct way to handle this? Continue working on properties of an Object which represents an anonymous type? Surely there must be something better.

EDIT:
Robert - Thanks for your suggestions. It turned out that I did NOT have a navigation property to SubCategories. The reason being that the people who came before me designed the database such that all top level categories end up with an artificial product_cat_parent_uid (just some random GUID). It doesn't point to a real product category in the database - it just acts as a placeholder. I question why they didn't just use NULL but it's too late to change it. At any rate since the item doesn't exist in the database, the database itself doesn't have the foreign key since it's faking the link. The databse won't create the link with product categories pointing to a product categorie that is not in the database. I did use your suggestion to find more information about what could be done and I used this article ([Entity Framework - Add Navigation Property Manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465855/entity-framework-add-navigation-property-manually)) to add those links I need.

The question still remains though - can I get strong typing within the ItemDataBind event?

Comment: Doesn't your Categories EF class have a navigation property to SubCategories?  If not, start there and add one.  Then it'd be two queries: `var Menu=db.Categories.Where(c=>c.product_cat_parent_uid = GUIDs.GlobalGuids.RootCategoryUid); db.Categories.Load();` I believe.

Comment: Alternatively, you could `var Menu=db.Categories.Include(c=>c.SubCategories).Include(c=>c.SubCategories.SubCatgories).Where(c=>c.product_cat_parent_uid = GUIDs.GlobalGuids.RootCategoryUid)` if you only need a few deep.